# Iframe(soundcloud player) shinks automatically. Can't find the source

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe, soundcloud

I'm currently editing a wordpress template - http://edenmuzik.ca/ and I'm having troubles with the soundcloud player. The code I have now is contained within a wordpress page that the template loads with ajax(i'm assuming)

```
    <iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/39874306&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;visual=true" height="450" width="100%" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The player contained within the music section resizes automatically once that page finishes loading but it keeps its high which I specify as 450 up until the page finishes loading.

I checked all css rules to make sure nothing is conflicting there... Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `450px` would be the way to hard code that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want it to display `450px` high, you need to set `450px` in your inline style.**

Based on the question I read above, are you saying you **want** it to be `450px`?

It would appear you are attempting to load the `iframe` with improper `HTML`, so your `450px` value isn't actually being applied.

**Here to help further if you'd like.**

Comment: That seemed to take care of it. Very much appreciated!